# Javascript match two arrays with substring search

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I really appreciate all your help on this. I have two arrays, the first is a file name without extension and the second includes an extension. I need to match the file names and output a third array of the matches.

```
ArrayFileName = [one, two, three, three, five, six, ten]
ArrayFileNameWExt = [one.txt, two.txt, three.txt, ten.wmf, eleven.cgm]
```

Output array would be

```
NewArrayFileNameWExt = [one.txt, two.txt, three.txt, ten.wmf]
```

Thank you for all your help.
Maxine

Comment: Actually, the second array and your expected output is the same, is that ok?

Comment: Yes because it matched the items in the first array. I guess I should have put some values in the first array that did not match

Comment: Can you improve the sample data, so we can understand better your goal?

Comment: Are the extensions always the same? Always `.txt`?

Comment: no the extensions vary

Comment: What to do if filenames does not match?

Comment: Updated example. Hope it makes things a little more clearer

Comment: If file name does not match do not include it in the third array

Comment: Sorry ten.wmf would be in the third array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can simple get this done

```
var ArrayFileName = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'five', 'six', 'ten'];
var ArrayFileNameWExt = ['one.txt', 'two.txt', 'three.txt', 'ten.wmf', 'eleven.cgm'];
var FinalArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < ArrayFileName.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < ArrayFileNameWExt.length; j++) {
        var temp = ArrayFileNameWExt[j].split(".");
        if(ArrayFileName[i]==temp[0]){
            FinalArray.push(ArrayFileNameWExt[j]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me. How would I find items that do not match? I tried changing the ArrayFileName[i]!==temp[0] but that didn't work. @Muhammad Sufian

Comment: @MaxineHammett you can find the code for this purpose here
https://codepen.io/sufian4199/pen/jXoRwR

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily with [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the second array and using a regular expression to test if each `filename` is include on the first array:

```js
ArrayFileName = [
  "one", "two", "three", "three", "five", "six", "ten", "dot.dot"
];

ArrayFileNameWExt = [
  "one.txt",
  "two.txt",
  "three.txt",
  "ten.wmf",
  "eleven.cgm",
  "dot.dot.csv",
  "foo",
  ".",
  ""
];

let res = ArrayFileNameWExt.filter(x =>
{
    let matchs = x.match(/(.*)\.(.*)$/);
    return ArrayFileName.includes(matchs && matchs[1]);
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for feedback @Aioros, I have updated for catch that.

Comment: @MaxineHammett if this helps you, please, take into consideration to choose this answer as accepted, same is valid for other answer that are useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```js
var ArrayFileName = ["one", "two", "three", "three", "five", "six"];
var ArrayFileNameWExt = ["one.txt", "two.txt", "three.txt", "ten.wmf"];

var NewArrayFileNameWExt = ArrayFileNameWExt
    .filter(file => ArrayFileName.includes(file.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".")));
        
console.log(NewArrayFileNameWExt);
```

Or in a slightly more readable way:

```
var NewArrayFileNameWExt = ArrayFileNameWExt.filter(function(file) {
    var filename = file.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".");
    return ArrayFileName.includes(filename);
});
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted, it contemplates filenames with `.` in the middle. +1. Note, you can improve the answer with a working example...

Comment: Thanks @Shidersz. Good suggestion, I converted my code into a working snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through both arrays and do a string comparison.
You could also do ArrayFileNameWExt[extName].indexOf(ArrayFileName[fName]) != -1

```
for(fName in ArrayFileName){
 for(extName in ArrayFileNameWExt){
  if(ArrayFileNameWExt[extName].split('.')[0] == ArrayFileName[fName]){
   NewArrayFileNameWExt.push(ArrayFileNameWExt[extName];
  }
 }
}
```

That should do it.

If the filename has a '.' in it, do element.indexOf(string) != -1

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: This will not work if the filename has a `.` in it, like `my.file.txt`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I also provided the indexOf option before your comment.

Comment: How would I use the indexOf option. The original code didn't work for me.

Comment: StringThatIAmSearchingThrough.indexOf(StringThatIAmSearchingFor) != -1

anything other than -1 means that that index is where the string starts. So if you get a 0, that means that the string you are searching for starts at the beginning of the other string that you are searching inside. If you need another explanation, let me know. Alternatively, check out that link I included above.

Comment: I MEANT to say that -1 means that the string is not found inside the other one. Anything other than that means it starts at that index so if indexOf(x) returns anything other than -1, it was found, and whatever it returns is where it was found.

Answer (score 1):

Use the array filter method:

```
NewArrayFileNameWExt = ArrayFileNameWExt.filter(filename => {
    ArrayFileName.indexOf(filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')) != -1
};
```

This also accounts for files such as `my.filename.txt`